# How do I package my node project files and deploy them to my server?

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs non open source web application project that I want to deploy to a production server and/or a staging server. Is there a default way for this, or some tool that does it? I want to package all files needed and exclude the files not needed like the `.git` folder, the tests and other files like `Gruntfile`, `package.json` and so on.

I could of course manually package the files in a tar.gz file and send them to the correct server. But I was hoping to find a more complete and configurable tool that can do it for me.

Comment: I find it curious that you want a deploy-tool but want to copy the files to servers manually. Normally one would use a deploy-tool that takes care of it all, for example capistrano. You might find some ideas in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199277/best-practices-for-deploying-tools-scripts-to-production).

Comment: I don't want to do copy the files manually. I mean that I could solve the task of getting the files to the server in that way, but i _do_ want a tool for this. I'll check out your link and suggestion.

Comment: Ah I see I completely misread that part.

Comment: Just as an FYI, I think keeping a package.json in your server might be a good idea. It allows your to maintain and do non breaking updates and keep a track of the versions of the npm modules you run. Plus, if you use have a git server, you can version your own app and update it as its packaged as an internal private NPM of its own.

Answer (score 1):

Might be not exactly what you're asking for, but i like `git` for automated deployment.

You could have branches like `staging` and `production`, which are checked out on the remote server.

You can set up a [git hook](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) like `post-receive` to update those remotely, every time you merge changes into those branches.

Here's a tutorial: http://wekeroad.com/2011/09/17/deploying-a-site-with-git-hooks